# Taxonomy term related content

Tags: taxonomy-terms

When click on any term, content related to that term should be displayed on the right hand side of a page. I have my taxonomy tree on left sidebar using Drupal API function.

What I had done is:

1. Created view with content type, containing all products related to
   taxonomy terms.
2. Add a field in that content type with field type "term reference"
   and widget type "simple hierarchical select" module.

Now what should I do in order to filter the term based content? Any Ideas?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/150942/taxonomy-term-related-content ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, sounds like you maybe want to use a contextual filter for the taxonomy term TID, and embed as a block in the sidebar for taxonomy pages.

This may help: http://dannyenglander.com/blog/using-views-contextual-filters-create-related-content-block-drupal-7

Steps to help:

- create a relationship, Content: Taxonomy terms on node, choose taxonomy, check require this relationship
- add contextual filter, Taxonomy Term: Term ID, select the relationship you just made, check "provide default value- Taxonomy term ID from URL, Load default filter from term page.

Just checked on a vanilla install, and that worked a charm for me...

Comment: Thanku Daniel for your reply, but how should I get the specific path when click on any taxonomy term?Because What I have understand is, first I should get the path of term on the basis of tid then can use contextual filter. Beacuse the current scenario is when I click on any term nothing change in the url

Comment: Edited above to add relationship steps.

Comment: Thanku @daniel, but I think you didnt get my point. I have taxonomy tree fetched using drupal api function so how can I link these terms ?

Comment: I have the tid of each term just and name :(